# Element-wise operation with two vectors of a data frame in R

Tags: r

My first question here: how to apply an efficient routine that iterates values of two vectors (pairwise) of a given data frame?

To be more specific, consider the following example using the following data frame:

```
df0 <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,2,3,1,3,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1),nrow=6,ncol=2))
colnames(df0) <- c("value","frequency")
```

The first column is a real value and the second column is a frequency (or weights). NOTICE: the weights have to be strictly positive, they might be repeated, they not necessarily add up to one (because of repetition).

I am performing the following LOOP to calculate my function P. This P is supposed to be a number between 0 and 1.

```
# Define two parameters
K = 1/2
alpha = 0

# LOOP
mattemp <- matrix(,nrow=length(df0$value), ncol=length(df0$value))

for(i in 1:length(df0$value)) {
  for(j in 1:length(df0$value)) {

    mattemp[i,j] <- df0$frequency[i]^(1+alpha) * df0$frequency[j] * abs(df0$value[i]-df0$value[j])

    P <- K * sum(mattemp)
  }
}
```

Basically, my function P is calculating:

```
P = K * (0.4^alpha * 0.2 * |1-2| + 0.4^alpha * 0.1 * |1-3| + ...
```

This code works perfectly well as long as the matrix is small.

However, I am trying to implement this routine for a big matrix (5400 x 5400) and this LOOP does not seem to find an end.

I already tried to loop it using a `foreach` command (using `%dopar%`), but it does not work as well.

Is there a smart and concise routine that R can handle??? It does not need to follow the above structure, as long as it is efficient.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df$nval <- (df0$value - mean(df0$value)) / sd(df0$value)
ij <- combn(nrow(df0), 2)
foo <- sum(df0$frequency[ij[1, ]] ^ (1 + alpha) * df0$frequency[ij[2, ]] * abs(df0$nval[ij[1, ]] - df0$nval[ij[2, ]]))
P <- K*2*sum(foo)
```

**Reasoning**: Basically you are testing every possible permutation between frequencies and normalized values. We use `combn` to create half of those. We then just vectorize the whole thing. Since `combn` only gives unique combinations, we need to multiply by 2. [Keep in mind that we don't need the values on the diagonal, as `abs(df0$value[i] - df0$value[i])` is equal to `0`, and we are only missing cases where `i=j` and `j=i`, so that's why we multiply by 2.] We then multiply by `K` and get P.

It's not clear how you want to normalize, so I just substracted the mean and divided that by the standard deviation. If you meant something else, you yourself can change it accordingly.

**Edit1**: Big thanks to @alexis_laz for finding a mistake and suggesting improvements that almost double the speed!

**Edit2**: Adjusted script to fit changed requirements.

Comment: Are you sure about this step here: `vald <- abs(val[,1] - val[,2])`? You get P=0.02 and I get P=0.18.

Comment: Perhaps, you could avoid calling `combn` twice by calling it on indices (`combn(nrow(df0), 2)`) and, then, indexing "value" and "frequency". And, also, it seems that `[, 1]` and `[, 2]` should be `[1, ]` and `[2, ]` respectively?

Comment: economics_sunysb Sorry, made a mistake (that @alexis_laz also pointed out). I copied the wrong code from the command line :D Fixed it now, it should return the correct result.

Comment: @alexis_laz I tried to implement your suggestion, but I can't figure it out completely... After `bar <- combn(nrow(df0),2)`, would there be a fast way to index `value` and `frequency` with `bar`? Because `bar` is a matrix. I tried to index both rows separately and then combine with `cbind`, but maybe you know a faster way?

Comment: @Laterow : I was, also, thinking about rows separately; `ij = combn(nrow(df0), 2)` and, then, `sum(df0$frequency[ij[1, ]] ^ (1 + alpha) * df0$frequency[ij[2, ]] * abs(df0$value[ij[1, ]] - df0$value[ij[2, ]]))`.

Comment: Implemented, thanks a lot for your suggestions :) If there is a better way to credit you, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for all attempts so far. There is something that still intrigues me: this number P should be something between 0 and 1. The code works well for the toy example I gave, but when I implement in my real database, it delivers something greater than 1 (by far...). The code is super fast, though. Does anybody have any extra suggestion? I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't know, I tried some different things and in all cases your script and our script give the same results. Are you sure that the data and the formula are correct? I don't know what else to suggest, sorry :(

Comment: Don't worry @Laterow! You already helped a lot. Will try to figure it out. Certainly it is a minor detail. When I accumulate sufficient reputation in here, I will upvote your answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have found out 2 things: 1) `ij <- combn(nrow(df0), 2)` still doesn't solve the problem since we need all permutations. The problem is that the number of permutations is huge and brings back the dimensionality problem. 2) For P to be between 0 and 1,  one has to "normalize" `df0$value` by its mean and include K=1/2 in this formula. That is all I got. The problem is still open apparently... Thanks for all support guys.

Comment: I changed the script accordingly. However, from this point on you'll have to use your own knowledge of R to further tweak the script. The whole idea of `combn` and applying it in a vectorized manner answers your question, i.e. how to effectively apply your formula to every permutation of a vector's elements. Any further tweaks will have to come from yourself.